# How to fix Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP

Tags: performance, lighthouse

Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load. Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_FCP) (NO_FCP)

Comment: Can you give more details? You are running lighthouse from DevTools or CLI? Does it happen reliably on the same website? can we reproduce it it?

Comment: I agree, details might be helpful here.

Comment: I searched for a list of error codes and troubleshooting section but did not find it in the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/ - but still you might find relevant information there.